# Linq Union and Take

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to fetch records from a DB table which has different categories. I want to fetch 1 random record from each level.

I've tried achieving this using:

```
  var results = (from o in db.tblName
                 where o.category== 1
                 orderby Guid.NewGuid()
                 select o).Take(1).Union
                 (from o in db.tblName
                  where o.category == 2
                  orderby Guid.NewGuid()
                  select o).Take(1).Union
                 (from o in db.tblName
                  where o.category == 3
                  orderby Guid.NewGuid()
                  select o).Take(1).Union
                 (from o in db.tblName
                   where o.category == 4
                   orderby Guid.NewGuid()
                   select o).Take(1);
```

Using the above code resulted in 1 record fetched instead of 4.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the last thing you are doing there is take(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because each `Take` is applied to the result of all the preceding `Union`s in the chain, i.e.

```
a.Take(1).Union(b).Take(1)
```

You need to add parentheses to your `Take`s to make sure it's

```
a.Take(1).Union(b.Take(1))
```

Your query should look like this:

```
var results =
       ((from o in db.tblName where o.category== 1 orderby Guid.NewGuid() select o).Take(1))
.Union((from o in db.tblName where o.category == 2 orderby Guid.NewGuid() select o).Take(1))
.Union((from o in db.tblName where o.category == 3 orderby Guid.NewGuid() select o).Take(1))
.Union((from o in db.tblName where o.category == 4 orderby Guid.NewGuid() select o).Take(1));
```

You can further simplify the query as follows:

```
var categories = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
var result = categories.Select(
    c => (from o in db.tblName where o.category==c orderby Guid.NewGuid() select o).Take(1)
).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you do something like this, if I understand your requirement correctly.

```
 Random rnd = new Random();


    var results  = db.tblName.GroupBy( q => q.category )
                 .Select( g => g.ElementAt(rnd.Next(0, g.Count())) ).ToList();
```